# Can you help me use the I210 driver for OpenAvnu in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, 22.04, intel

I contacted Intel because I couldn't install the I210 driver, and they advised me to repost it on this forum.

## The original text is as follows.

I am trying to verify the operation using the I210 driver in openAvnu.

I encountered an error while executing `igb_avb` under the openAVnu source.

```
~/OpenAvnu/examples/simple_talker$ sudo ./simple_talker -i enp3s0 -t 2    
attaching to 0000:03:00.0    
attach failed! devpath=0000:03:00.0 (Unknown error -6)    
connect failed (Is a directory) - are you running as root?
```

The error occurred in the `igb.c` file at the following code. I tried modifying it as shown in the second code, but the error remains the same.

original code :

```
adapter->ldev = open("/dev/igb_avb", O_RDWR);
```

modified code :

```
adapter->ldev = open("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:03:00.0", O_RDWR);
```

After mount the driver, I verified that it exists even though I haven't installed sw driver additonally.

While I was downloading and installing the `igb_avb` source to use the I210 driver from openAVnu, I encountered an error.

used source link : https://github.com/Avnu/igb_avb

Although the build was successful, I encountered an error while performing insmod as follows.

```
~/OpenAvnu/lib/igb_avb/kmod$ sudo insmod ./igb_avb.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./igb_avb.ko: Key was rejected by service
```

============================================================================

Can you help me resolve this issue?

link : https://community.intel.com/t5/Embedded-Connectivity/Can-you-help-me-use-the-I210-driver-for-OpenAvnu-in-Ubuntu-22-04/m-p/1567913/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8bWVudGlvbl9zdWJzY3JpcHRpb258TFMxVkc4RjFCNUZHNFV8MTU2NzkxM3xBVF9NRU5USU9OU3xoSw#M5114

Comment: Does disabling secure boot work?